# Issue with Laravel ECS Deployment: Access denied for user 'forge'@'10.0.20.124'

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-rds, amazon-ecs, laravel

I am facing an issue with my Laravel application deployment on AWS ECS. The deployment process involves Jenkins, AWS ECR, and ECS. The new task is created, but there's an "Access Denied" error connecting to the RDS database. I have provided my deployment files for reference.

JenkinsFile:

```
pipeline {

    agent any

    environment {
        AWS_ACCOUNT_ID="794664785634"
        AWS_DEFAULT_REGION="us-east-1"
        IMAGE_REPO_NAME="product-mangement"
        IMAGE_TAG="${BUILD_NUMBER}"
        REPOSITORY_URI = "794664785634.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/product-mangement"
        ECS_CLUSTER = "product-mangement"
        ECS_SERVICE = "product-mangement"
    }

    stages {
        stage('Checkout Latest Source') {
            steps {
                git branch: 'master',
                url: 'https://github.com/jhon-123/product-mangement',
                credentialsId: 'jenkins_pta'
            }
        }
        stage('Logging into AWS ECR') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh """aws ecr get-login-password --region ${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION} | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}.amazonaws.com"""
                }
                 
            }
        }
        
        // Building Docker images
        stage('Building image') {
            steps{
                script {
                    dockerImage = docker.build "${IMAGE_REPO_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG}"
                }
            }
        }
   
        // Uploading Docker images into AWS ECR
        stage('Pushing to ECR') {
            steps{  
                script {
                    sh """docker tag ${IMAGE_REPO_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG} ${REPOSITORY_URI}:$IMAGE_TAG"""
                    sh """docker push ${AWS_ACCOUNT_ID}.dkr.ecr.${AWS_DEFAULT_REGION}.amazonaws.com/${IMAGE_REPO_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG}"""
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Deploy to ECS') {
            steps {
                sh "aws ecs update-service --cluster ${ECS_CLUSTER} --service ${ECS_SERVICE} --force-new-deployment"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Dockerfile:

```
# Use the official PHP image as a base
FROM php:8.1-fpm

ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER 1

# Arguments defined in docker-compose.yml
ARG user
ARG uid

USER root

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git \
    curl \
    libpng-dev \
    libonig-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    zip \
    unzip

# Clear cache
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install PHP extensions
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql mbstring exif pcntl bcmath gd

# Get latest Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# Create system user to run Composer and Artisan Commands
# RUN useradd -G www-data,root -u $uid -d /home/$user $user
# RUN mkdir -p /home/$user/.composer && \
  # chown -R $user:$user /home/$user

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /var/www

# Copy the project files into the container
COPY . /var/www

# Copy .env.example to .env
COPY .env.prod .env

# Install Composer dependencies
RUN composer install

# Cache configuration
RUN php artisan config:clear
RUN php artisan config:cache

# Generate Laravel application key
RUN php artisan key:generate

# Copy the start script into the container
COPY script.sh /var/www/script.sh

# Make the script executable
RUN chmod +x /var/www/script.sh

# Expose port 8000
EXPOSE 8000

# show message
RUN echo "ehllo"

# Run the start script as the CMD
CMD ["/var/www/script.sh"]
```

script.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Run Laravel migrations
php artisan migrate

# Seed Database
php artisan db:seed
echo "seeded successfully"

# Start the Laravel application
php artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8000
```

Problem:
The new task is created, but there is an "Access Denied" error connecting to the RDS database.
The `.env.prod` file contains the correct RDS connection details.

.env.prod:

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=prod
APP_KEY=base64:LyxaydSCa8HIgUdaLLQCPehtSK2siVr0o+bT6jcXWmM=
APP_DEBUG=false
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=product-management.c7ebhtqyydqk.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=product-management
#DB_USERNAME=laravel
#DB_PASSWORD=secret

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailhog
MAIL_PORT=1025
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"
```

Question:

What could be causing the "Access Denied" error in the deployment process, and how can I resolve it? Any insights or suggestions for troubleshooting would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have a look in CloudTrail, find the matching event. CloudTrail is a bit of a pain to use, but once you find the event it will tell you which user / role is trying to access what, based on that you will know what needs more permissions.

Comment: i have to add CloudTrail service with ECS?

Comment: No, CloudTrail is the AWS audit log. It automatically records a number of days history even if you don't explicitly enable it. AWS is complex, training is generally required to understand how it works.

Comment: Dear! I can see logs in Task logs there I'm getting access denies the issue of database but when i ssh into the ECS cluster and run migrate or see command then works successfully but it does work when I clear cache with ``php artisan config:cache`` otherwise there also get access denied issue'

Comment: I have created secret manager and added ``username`` and ``password`` of RDS into the secret manger and used in the Task definition as environment variables but I'm a little bit confused about why it's getting the default database from ``config/database.php``